# Cloud Removal from Landsat Data

Tags: open-source-gis, remote-sensing, landsat

I'm trying to remove clouds from Landsat 5,7 and 8 data. I'm also trying to do this using only open source options, avoiding ArcGIS. I'm familiar with python and have some QGIS experience. Originally, I was trying to use the Semi-Automatic Classification model in QGIS, but it is giving me a lot of problems, and doesn't always output actual classifications (it often just returns a uniformly valued square...). Can anyone point me in the direction of a better option?

Comment: I would check it last year's GSoC project with Opticks lead to usable results http://opticks.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=9372446

Comment: Are you aware of the Landsat 8 Quality Assessment Band? http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8QualityAssessmentBand.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest taking a look at **fmask** by [Zhe Zhu](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zhe_Zhu2/publications)

Con:

- neither Python nor QGIS

Pros:

- availlable as [matlab](https://code.google.com/p/fmask/) or [C](https://code.google.com/p/cfmask/) executable
- great performance in detecting clouds as well as cloud shadows
- straightforward use

I highly recommend giving it a try. The executables can be obtained from the links and so far our team hasn't found a superior product which is distributed free of charge.

Comment: Would people be interested in a python version? I have got pretty good results from a python version of fmask that I've built. If there is a need for it I could publish the code.

Comment: Is it the code working for LT8 before failure of the TIRS or the one allready built for Sentinel-2 (fmask version 3.2 and higher)? Anyway: I'm interested.

Comment: I am busy implementing the use of the 'cirrus' band in L8. I'll let you know how it goes. The failure of the TIRS meant a bit of a rewrite. I'm glad there is some interest.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to identify cloud pixels in Landsat 8 scenes using the following code. I have included some python / pseudo-code below which will return possible cloud pixels. This is the first pass of identifying the potential cloud layer taken from [this paper by Zhu and Woodcock (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425714002259).

The paper also details a second pass that further refines the result by excluded misidentified cloud pixels. You should have a look at that too. The method was developed for Landsat 7 so it should work for all Landsat cases.

```
def calc_ndsi():
     green = get_green_band()
     swir = get_swir_band()
     return (green - swir)/(green + swir)

def calc_ndvi():
    nir = get_nir_band()
    red = get_red_band()
    return (nir - red)/(nir + red)

def calc_basic_test():
    band_7_test = get_band_seven()
    temp_test = where temp is less than 27 deg C
    ndsi_test = where calc_ndsi < 0.8
    ndvi_test = where calc_ndvi < 0.8
    basic_test = np.logical_and.reduce((band_7_test,
                                    temp_test,
                                    ndsi_test,
                                    ndvi_test))
    return basic_test

def calc_whiteness():
    blue = get blue
    green = get green
    red = get red
    mean_vis = (blue + green + red) / 3
    whiteness = (np.abs((blue - mean_vis)/mean_vis) + 
             np.abs((green - mean_vis)/mean_vis) +
             np.abs((red - mean_vis)/mean_vis))
    whiteness[np.where(whiteness>1)] = 1
    return whiteness

def calc_whiteness_test():
    whiteness_test = where calc_whiteness() < 0.7
    return whiteness_test

def calculate_hot_test():
    band = 'rtoa_'
    blue = get blue
    red = get red
    hot_test = (blue - 0.5*red - 0.08) > 0
    return hot_test

def swirnir_test():
    nir = get NIR
    swir = get SWIR
    return (nir/swir) > 0.75

def calc_pcp():
    return np.logical_and.reduce((calc_basic_test(),
                              calc_whiteness_test(),
                              calculate_hot_test(),
                              swirnir_test()))
```

So, `calc_pcp()` will identify the potential cloud pixels in your image.

Note that this method uses the TIRS bands (to get the temperature) in Landsat 8 which are currently not working. Additionally, this method uses data which has already undergone atmospheric correction.

Identifying clouds in remote sensing images is more than a colour processing issue, although calculating the 'whiteness' of the cloud is included in the test.

You should compare the results you get with the Landsat 8 Quality Assessment band.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2022: updated to use the Wayback machine on the link I was linking to in 2015. There. Now the link works

## You might try [this solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20131221002847/http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Automated_cloud_detection)  :
Disclaimer

I've never removed cloud data before.

## Opinion:

It seems like a color processing issue: clouds are a white-gray color. As long as you don't have snow or other large white objects in your ground plane, you could do a search for all pixels that match a criteria of having full red AND full green AND and full blue colors.
as to how to do this... try the solution posted above.

Comment: There are many other objects in these images which can be as white as clouds. Using this method would not be sufficient in identifying cloud pixels.

Comment: The link you provided has no any resources, kindly update

Comment: updated resources.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this page
http://gistack.rozblog.com/post/32/qa_cloudmask_ports.html
at the bottom of this page you can download an erdas imagine model
it takes landsat8 QA band and replace cloud pixel values with 0